Fail to load external data file "onnx model"in onnx runtime in devexpress application?
I have put onnx model in my wwwroot/js folder but it is not being detected and I am getting this error.
error = Error: failed to load external data file: js/sevensegment.onnx
    at gn (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/onnxruntime-web/dist/ort.min.js:1806:20708)
    at async Co.fetchModelAndCopyToWasmMemory (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/onnxruntime-web/dist/ort.min.js:18...

When trying to access the razor file
//const modelPromise = ort.InferenceSession.create("~/js/sevensegment.onnx");
//const modelPromise = ort.InferenceSession.create("/js/sevensegment.onnx");
//const modelPromise = ort.InferenceSession.create("js/sevensegment.onnx");  tried different paths...

(async () => {
    try {
        const modelPath = "js/sevensegment.onnx";
        // Ensure this path is correct
        const session = await ort.InferenceSession.create(modelPath);
        console.log("Model loaded successfully");

        // Add your code to use the model here
        // Example:
        // const inputTensor = new ort.Tensor(...);
        // const outputTensor = await session.run({ input: inputTensor });
        // console.log(outputTensor);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to load model:", error);
    }
})();


Tried different approaches, new to dev express blazor.
this is working in a simple HTML + javascript file that I used.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>YOLOv8 Object Detection</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/onnxruntime-web/dist/ort.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        canvas {
            display:block;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-top:10px;
        }
        video {
            display:block;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-top:10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="videoElement" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
    <button id="detectButton">Detect Objects</button>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <script>
        const videoElement = document.getElementById('videoElement');
        const detectButton = document.getElementById('detectButton');

        // Get webcam feed on page load
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
            .then(stream => {
                videoElement.srcObject = stream;
            });

        /**
         * Function to prepare input image for YOLOv8 object detection
         * @param buf Content of uploaded file
         * @returns Array of pixels
         */
        async function prepare_input(buf) {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                const img = new Image();
                img.src = URL.createObjectURL(buf);
                img.onload = () => {
                    const [img_width,img_height] = [img.width, img.height]
                    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    canvas.width = 640;
                    canvas.height = 640;
                    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    context.drawImage(img,0,0,640,640);
                    const imgData = context.getImageData(0,0,640,640);
                    const pixels = imgData.data;

                    const red = [], green = [], blue = [];
                    for (let index=0; index<pixels.length; index+=4) {
                        red.push(pixels[index]/255.0);
                        green.push(pixels[index+1]/255.0);
                        blue.push(pixels[index+2]/255.0);
                    }
                    const input = [...red, ...green, ...blue];
                    resolve([input, img_width, img_height])
                }
            })
        }

        detectButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
            const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = videoElement.videoWidth;
            canvas.height = videoElement.videoHeight;
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            // Draw current frame from video onto the canvas
            ctx.drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            const imageBlob = await new Promise(resolve => canvas.toBlob(resolve, 'image/jpeg'));
            const boxes = await detect_objects_on_image(imageBlob);
            draw_image_and_boxes(imageBlob, boxes);
        });

        /**
         * Function to draw the image from the provided file
         * and bounding boxes of detected objects on
         * top of the image
         * @param file Uploaded file object
         * @param boxes Array of bounding boxes in format [[x1,y1,x2,y2,object_type,probability],...]
         */
        function draw_image_and_boxes(file, boxes) {
            const img = new Image()
            img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            img.onload = () => {
                const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
                canvas.width = img.width;
                canvas.height = img.height;
                const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
                ctx.strokeStyle = "#00FF00";
                ctx.lineWidth = 3;
                ctx.font = "18px serif";
                boxes.forEach(([x1,y1,x2,y2,label]) => {
                    ctx.strokeRect(x1,y1,x2-x1,y2-y1);
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
                    const width = ctx.measureText(label).width;
                    ctx.fillRect(x1,y1,width+10,25);
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
                    ctx.fillText(label, x1, y1+18);
                });
            }
        }

        /**
         * Function receives an image, passes it through YOLOv8 neural network
         * and returns an array of detected objects and their bounding boxes
         * @param buf Input image body
         * @returns Array of bounding boxes in format [[x1,y1,x2,y2,object_type,probability],..]
         */
        async function detect_objects_on_image(buf) {
            const [input,img_width,img_height] = await prepare_input(buf);
            const output = await run_model(input);
            return process_output(output,img_width,img_height);
        }

        // Move the model loading outside of the run_model function
        const modelPromise = ort.InferenceSession.create("sevensegment.onnx");

        /**
         * Function used to pass provided input tensor to YOLOv8 neural network and return result
         * @param input Input pixels array
         * @returns Raw output of neural network as a flat array of numbers
         */
        async function run_model(input) {
            const model = await modelPromise; // Use the pre-loaded model
            input = new ort.Tensor(Float32Array.from(input),[1, 3, 640, 640]);
            const outputs = await model.run({images:input});
            return outputs["output0"].data;
        }

        /**
         * Function used to convert RAW output from YOLOv8 to an array of detected objects.
         * Each object contains the bounding box of this object, the type of object, and the probability
         * @param output Raw output of YOLOv8 network
         * @param img_width Width of the original image
         * @param img_height Height of original image
         * @returns Array of detected objects in a format [[x1,y1,x2,y2,object_type,probability],..]
         */
        function process_output(output, img_width, img_height) {
            let boxes = [];
            for (let index=0;index<8400;index++) {
                const [class_id,prob] = [...Array(80).keys()]
                    .map(col => [col, output[8400*(col+4)+index]])
                    .reduce((accum, item) => item[1]>accum[1] ? item : accum,[0,0]);
                if (prob < 0.5) {
                    continue;
                }
                const label = yolo_classes[class_id];
                const xc = output[index];
                const yc = output[8400+index];
                const w = output[2*8400+index];
                const h = output[3*8400+index];
                const x1 = (xc-w/2)/640*img_width;
                const y1 = (yc-h/2)/640*img_height;
                const x2 = (xc+w/2)/640*img_width;
                const y2 = (yc+h/2)/640*img_height;
                boxes.push([x1,y1,x2,y2,label,prob]);
            }

            boxes = boxes.sort((box1,box2) => box2[5]-box1[5])
            const result = [];
            while (boxes.length>0) {
                result.push(boxes[0]);
                boxes = boxes.filter(box => iou(boxes[0],box)<0.7);
            }
            return result;
        }

        /**
         * Function calculates "Intersection-over-union" coefficient for specified two boxes
         * https://pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/07/intersection-over-union-iou-for-object-detection/.
         * @param box1 First box in format: [x1,y1,x2,y2,object_class,probability]
         * @param box2 Second box in format: [x1,y1,x2,y2,object_class,probability]
         * @returns Intersection over union ratio as a float number
         */
        function iou(box1,box2) {
            return intersection(box1,box2)/union(box1,box2);
        }

        /**
         * Function calculates union area of two boxes.
         *     :param box1: First box in format [x1,y1,x2,y2,object_class,probability]
         *     :param box2: Second box in format [x1,y1,x2,y2,object_class,probability]
         *     :return: Area of the boxes union as a float number
         * @param box1 First box in format [x1,y1,x2,y2,object_class,probability]
         * @param box2 Second box in format [x1,y1,x2,y2,object_class,probability]
         * @returns Area of the boxes union as a float number
         */
        function union(box1,box2) {
            const [box1_x1,box1_y1,box1_x2,box1_y2] = box1;
            const [box2_x1,box2_y1,box2_x2,box2_y2] = box2;
            const box1_area = (box1_x2-box1_x1)*(box1_y2-box1_y1)
            const box2_area = (box2_x2-box2_x1)*(box2_y2-box2_y1)
            return box1_area + box2_area - intersection(box1,box2)
        }

        /**
         * Function calculates the intersection area of two boxes
         * @param box1 First box in format [x1,y1,x2,y2,object_class,probability]
         * @param box2 Second box in format [x1,y1,x2,y2,object_class,probability]
         * @returns Area of intersection of the boxes as a float number
         */
        function intersection(box1,box2) {
            const [box1_x1,box1_y1,box1_x2,box1_y2] = box1;
            const [box2_x1,box2_y1,box2_x2,box2_y2] = box2;
            const x1 = Math.max(box1_x1,box2_x1);
            const y1 = Math.max(box1_y1,box2_y1);
            const x2 = Math.min(box1_x2,box2_x2);
            const y2 = Math.min(box1_y2,box2_y2);
            return (x2-x1)*(y2-y1)
        }

        /**
         * Array of YOLOv8 class labels
         */
        const yolo_classes = [
            '.','0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9','-','kwh'
        ];
    </script>
</body>
</html>


This is working and I used a local server to open it and it works. But when I moved to blazor project it did not detect onnx model or am I missing something?
